# What type of visa for UK visit?

Tags: visas, uk, family, spouses, colombian-citizens

I am a UK national living abroad in Colombia. My husband is Colombian. Do we need to apply for a standard UK visitor visa? I'm asking because I answered "yes" to a question in the application, which was "is your main purpose of the trip to visit a close family member?".

My purpose is to visit my family and introduce my partner to his in-laws. For him, it is this and tourism too. We only intend to visit for one or two months.

Answer (score 1):

Your husband needs to apply for a visa since he is a visa national. As he doesn’t intend to settle in the U.K. the Standard Visit visa is his only option for a visit of 6 months or less.   https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y I think you’ve chosen the correct answer for his main reason for visiting the U.K. if you’re intending to spend a lot of the time visiting with your family members - ‘Tourism, including visiting family & friends’ could be the choice depending on the itinerary you’re planning. You should think carefully about the correct premise for your visit, it needs to make sense in the light of your husband’s circumstances and be credible from the ECO’s point of view. See  https://gayotfow.wordpress.com/2018/04/13/if-you-want-to-hang-out-youve-gotta-take-her-out/ for a detailed analysis/answer

Comment: @David Richerby I will add my earlier comment to my answer

Comment: Thanks. Please post answers as answers. Don't post an answer as a comment and a link as an answer, as that bypasses all the site's quality control mechanisms.